# Stub out a request to google maps api in my tests

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, google-maps-api-3, fakeweb

I try to mock out geocoding request by using FakeWeb (in cucumber/rails).
When I block all http requests I get the message:

```
Real HTTP connections are disabled. Unregistered request: GET 
http://maps.google.com/maps/api/geocode/json?..... (FakeWeb::NetConnectNotAllowedError)
```

So I registered the url by trying:

```
FakeWeb.register_uri(:any, %r|http://maps\.google\.com/maps/|, :json 
=> { 
    "status": "OK", 
....}
```

I get the error "A JSON text must at least contain two octets!" (MultiJson::DecodeError)
I'm not sure what information to return. And how FakeWeb can return json data..
Does someone have a solution for stubbing out server requests to the google maps api?

Comment: You probably want to make json a string, not a ruby hash.

Answer (score 2):

The `"A JSON text must at least contain two octets!"` error indicates that the JSON string your are using to stub the response is not valid.  Try running `MultiJson.decode(json_string)` with your json string before stubbing with it; that should help you pinpoint the error.

If you don't want to deal with the details of stubbing the google maps API, you may want to look into using [VCR](http://relishapp.com/myronmarston/vcr); it will record a real response for you and use that to stub the request on subsequent test runs.  It's a much easier way to get realistic stubbed responses in your tests.